# How to run ffmpeg as a subprocess and wait for the task to finish (fastapi)

Tags: ffmpeg, subprocess, fastapi

I'm creating a site that runs ffmpeg on the web using fastapi.

```
@router.post("/dir/Conver") 
async def ffmpeg_Conversion(request: Request):
    data = await request.json()

    file_path = data.get('file_path')
    saturation = float(data.get('saturation', 1.0))  
    brightness = float(data.get('brightness', 0.0))  
    contrast = float(data.get('contrast', 1.0))
    size = data.get('size','3840x2160')
    bitlayer = data.get('bitlayer',8000)
    codec = data.get('codec','libx264')
    formatstr=data.get('format','MP4')


    savepath = './UserFolder' + file_path

    directory = os.path.dirname(savepath)
    last_directory = os.path.basename(savepath)
    
    last_directory=str(last_directory).split('.')[0]
    print("last_directory : ---------------------" + last_directory)

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_datetime = current_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f')


    ffmpeg_command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-i', savepath,
        '-vf', f'eq=saturation={1+saturation/100}:brightness={brightness/100}:contrast={1+contrast/100}',
        '-s', size,
        '-c:v', codec,
        '-preset', 'medium',
        '-b:v', bitlayer,
        directory+'/'+last_directory+"_"+formatted_datetime+"."+formatstr
    ]

    subprocess.check_output(ffmpeg_command, text=True)
```

Using the code above, I created a function to convert the video.
And this function was given to a button on the web.

```
FileChan_yes.addEventListener('click', async () => { 
            startRotation();


            const file_path = 'path_to_your_file';  
            const contrastValue = contrastSlider.value;
            const brightnessValue = lightnessSlider.value;
            const saturationValue = saturationSlider.value;

            const Dir=document.getElementById('last_action_link');
            const savepath = Dir.value;

            const codecDropValue = codecDrop.value; 
            const formatDropValue = formatDrop.value;
            const FileSizeDropValue = FileSizeDrop.value;
            const bitDropValue  =   bitDrop.value;


            try {
                const response = await fetch(`/dir/Conver`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        file_path: savepath,
                        saturation: saturationValue,
                        brightness: brightnessValue,
                        contrast: contrastValue,
                        size: FileSizeDropValue,
                        bitlayer : bitDropValue,
                        codec : codecDropValue,
                        formatstr : formatDropValue
                    })
                    
                });

                
                if (response.ok) {
                    const result = await response.json();
                    console.log("Conversion successful:", result);
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Failed to convert the file.");
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error converting the file:", error);
            } finally {
                stopRotation();
            }
            

        });
```

When you press the button, first
startRotation(); the function is executed

When all tasks are completed, the stopRotation(); function is configured to be executed.

But currently it's not working properly...

stopRotation(); The function is executed as soon as the button is pressed.

await doesn't seem to work. What is the problem?